# What package has GNU sed for Solaris?

Tags: sed, software-installation, solaris

I need to use the features of GNU sed, instead of the built-in version under Solaris 10.

Which GNU package contains it?  I don't see it listed in the coreutils, and my Google searches haven't helped pinpoint it.

Comment: http://sunfreeware.com/

Comment: it actually is a rare thing that you do need to use the GNU features - they're almost all just shortcuts. A better way to address the problem might be writing more portable `sed` scripts. The most notable exception, though, involves multibyte characters in non-ASCII locales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU sed is bundled with releases newer than Solaris 10. Otherwise, you can easily build it from [source](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed) or retrieve it from [opencsw](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWgsed) or other freeware repositories.

Solaris 10 packages are listed in this pdf: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/pdf/817-0545.pdf

Comment: Thanks!  One search I did - Where can I get sed - obviously thought 'sed' was a typo